# "Tried to" versus "try to": The -ed suffix as an intervocalic tap

Tags: pronunciation, accent, north-american-english

This question isn't answered here:

- [Differentiate between past and present just by pronunciation when word is followed by d- or similiar sound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116431/differentiate-between-past-and-present-just-by-pronunciation-when-word-is-follow/282666#282666)

That question asks about what happens when the following word begins with a consonant in general. This one is asking about the various possibilities for an intervocalic tap if a following word is an unstressed function word beginning with /t/. It's also asking whether there's any possibility for regressive assimilation here.

---

I read this in American accent book. I quote the text exactly how it is written in the book:

> The suffix -ed is not pronounced precisely when it is linked to another consonant. For example, **mailed the** sounds very much like **mail the** in the following sentences:
>
> - I already mailed the letter.
> - I will mail the letter.
>
> The suffix -ed is not heard at all when it is linked to /t/ or /d/. For example **talked to** sounds identical to **talk to** in the following sentences:
>
> - I talked to her yesterday.
> - I talk to her every day.

Okay but then my question is, how do Americans distinguish between these two sentences:

- I try to call you.
- I tried to call you.

In the first sentence the /t/ will be realised by a voiced tap because it occurs between two vowels. In the second will we get a regular [t] and then a voiced tap? Will we get a double tap or a double length tap? Or will we just get a single tap? Or maybe here we will just get two regular /t/s?

Do native speakers differentiate between "I tried to call you" and "I try to call you" from the context?

Comment: You can hear the difference between "tried" and "try" when those sentences are spoken with an American accent. The "d" doesn't go away completely at the end of "mailed." "Mailed the" and "mail the" might sound very much alike, but they're not identical.

Comment: "I try to call you" is not proper English (including US English) so we wouldn't be confused about that.  The proper sentence would be "I will try to call you." which is very different from "I tried to call you."   FWIW, when I say "I tried to call you.", there is something extra going on with my tongue between the vowel sound in "tried" and the "t" in "to".  I'm afraid if you learn to say "I try to call you." for "I tried to call you.", it might sound odd.

Comment: Kristina, there are cases when "I try to call you" can be part of a grammatical sentence, e.g. "Every Monday I try to call you, and you never answer."

Comment: William Bloom- I know that. I was talking about linking. Tried‿to, the two stop consonants are linked together.

Comment: Zoltan- I know you meant "tried to." I guess the answer is YES, linked consonants are differentiated by context. If the meaning were every ambiguous, a speaker could repeat the sentence and pronounced the individual consonants more accurately. But it's not the case that "talked to" is *always* indistinguishable from "talk to", or "tried to" is always indistinguishable from "try to."

Comment: 'Your parents wrote saying they often try/tried to call you' is perhaps a better example.

Comment: "I('d) try to call you but you wouldn('t) take any calls." Note that especially in the first case the vowel is lenthened enough that keen listeners can spot what's going on. You seem obsessed with this non-issue because you keep asking the same question over and over again. Just listen and stop worrying about written forms. I wouldna said it if I hadna meant it.

Comment: *how do Americans distinguish between these two sentences*?  By listening to them, since they sound different.

Comment: Even though I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate of the linked question, that question only has one answer whose author explicitly states a desire to  "defer to an expert," so if anyone who commented above wants to actually answer in an **answer** over there, I think it would be a useful addition.

Comment: @sumelic Ok, so I've tried to give a decent answer for [that question over there](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116431/differentiate-between-past-and-present-just-by-pronunciation-when-word-is-follow/282666#282666). But, if you have a look at this re-edited one, I think you'd agree that this isn't really a dupe of that one! Any chance of a reopen vote here?

Comment: @Araucaria: Even with your edits, it still seems to me like this is just a more specific case of the other question. The other question nowhere says it is only "about what happens when the base form of a verb ends in a consonant." The verb "kill" is just given as an example. The original poster of this question never made this distinction either. I don't see why it warrants a new answer here. Should we get a third question about "pronunciation of -ed after voiceless consonants before a /t/", since the linked question uses an example word that ends in a voiced consonant?

Comment: @sumelic Hmm, well maybe, but I think the case of intervocalic taps (which I don't know the answer to, although I have an opinion) is one complicated area to far to integrate into that other question, imo.

Comment: @sumelic Have *now* edited the question to make it tap specific ... Will that help? (I'm not going to answer this question btw!)

Comment: Your own quote says it:  "**mailed the** sounds *very much* like **mail the**".  It doesn't say they are identical.